# Generic method is picking up type of base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following classes (trimmed to only show the basic structure):

```
public abstract class BaseModel {
    public bool PersistChanges() {
        // Context is of type "ObjectContext"
        DatabaseHelper.Context.SafelyPersistChanges(this);
    }
}

public static class ObjectContextExtensions {
    public static bool SafelyPersistChanges<T>(this ObjectContext oc, T obj) {
        // Persist the object using a transaction
    }
}

[Persistent("LEADS")]
public class Lead : BaseModel {
    // Extra properties
}

public class LeadsController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Save(Lead lead) {
        lead.PersistChanges()
    }
}
```

My **Lead** class derives from **BaseModel**, which contains a method to persist the object's changes to the database using a transaction. I implemented the transactional persist with an extension method. The problem is that by passing **this** to **SafelyPersistChanges** in my **BaseModel** class, the generic T on the extension method is set to **BaseModel**. However, since **BaseModel** isn't marked as a persistent object (which it cannot be), the ORM framework throws an exception.

Example:

```
Lead lead = LeadRepository.FindByNumber(2);
lead.SalesmanNumber = 4;
// Calls "ObjectContextExtensions.SafelyPersistChanges<BaseModel>(BaseModel obj)"
// instead of "ObjectContextExtensions.SafelyPersistChanges<Lead>(Lead obj)"
lead.PersistChanges();
```

The above block raises the following exception:

> Cannot create mapping for type 'SalesWeb.Data.BaseModel' without persistent attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension Methods are statically bound at compile time.  At the point in which SafelyPersistChanges is called, this is typed as BaseModel and hence your exception.  In order to get the behavior you want, you'll either need to do an ugly if statement with lots of casting or force the call to the derived class.

Make PersistChanges an abstract method.  Then implement the call in the derived classes with exactly the same code.

```
public class Lead { 
    public override bool PersistChanges() {
        // Context is of type "ObjectContext"
        DatabaseHelper.Context.SafelyPersistChanges(this);
    }
}
```

Now this will properly be Lead

Comment: Thanks! It creates code duplication, but I guess that's just a sacrifice I'll have to make. On the plus side, it gives models the opportunity to perform other operations before persisting themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I would have designed this differently, making "public bool PersistChanges()" call a virtual method, that is overridden in each subclass.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a "single" implementation, that varies against a type known by the caller.  Sounds like a job for Generics.

```
public static bool PersistChanges<T>(this T source)
  where T : BaseModel
{
        // Context is of type "ObjectContext"
//static property which holds a Context instance is dangerous.
        DatabaseHelper.Context.SafelyPersistChanges<T>(source);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
// change your code to this

public abstract class BaseModel<TDerived> where TDerived : BaseModel
{
    public bool PersistChanges() {
        // Context is of type "ObjectContext"
        DatabaseHelper.Context.SafelyPersistChanges((TDerived)this);
        //                                            ^
        // note the cast here: -----------------------|
    }
}

public class Lead : BaseModel<Lead> { }

// the rest of your code is unchanged
```

That would work, but I'd probably just follow the other suggestions and use a virtual method.